# How to use UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in my application.

I have no clue how to use it. I'm no Objective-C expert, and Objective-C documentation seems to be lacking. Could someone please explain to me the steps and code to do this?

I have it already in my view, but I don't know whether to make it an `IBOutlet`, or something else. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to explain what you *want* to use it for. Only then might someone begin to explain what to do, as there is surely lots of things one can do with a `UIWebView`.

Comment: Please do at least a little bit of searching for answers before posting a question expecting us to write code for you.  This is not a tutorial site, if you have made an attempt at implementing the WebView and have a specific issue - fine, if not - make some effort first.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't know whether to make it an Outlet

You should add an `IBOutlet` for your `UIWebView` because you need to tell it to load which web page.

Then you can use it like this:

```
// remember to add the 'http://' or `https://`
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:req];
```

Sometimes maybe you need to set `webView`'s delegate method:

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:


@interface RadioViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
...
@end
```

And set its delegate to `self`.

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

And add this method to do something you need.

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    // Add your code
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Since I just need to get this stuff done, how would I implement this after I control dragged and made an outlet? @property has been making me hate objective-c.

Comment: Add `NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:req];` to where you need to load a webpage.